# How to highlight different environments

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have number of Azure databricks workspaces and environments like dev, test, uat,sit,pre-prod and Prod.

The notebooks , code and objects are almost similar at each of these environments leading to often mistakes treating wrong environment for updates.

How do I highlight them ? It will help f I can colour title at top showing kind of env being used.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't believe there's a way to highlight, but there may be some things you can do to help differentiate.

#### Using `displayHTML`

You can use the `displayHTML` method in Databricks to show HTML at the beginning of each notebook.

```
displayHTML("""
<style>
h1 {
   background-color: red;
   color: black;
   padding: 25px;
}
</style>

<h1>Production</h1>
""")
```

[image]

#### Using a widget

If you don't have any widgets already, this may be the better option since widgets can be pinned to the top of the notebook.

```
dbutils.widgets.text("prod", "Production", "Environment")
```

[image]

Hope one of these helps until a better solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the Person icon in the top right corner you should see a list of your workspaces and a tick next to the active one.

This is as good as it gets.

Otherwise memorise the o=1234567890 part of the URL?!